# How to map a IP:Port on WAN to LAN?

Tags: iptables

I use a Linux machine as a router to route LAN *192.168.1.1/24* on `eth1` to WAN *172.16.1.5/24* on `eth0`, and the IP here are assined to this router.

Now I need to map a HP Jetdirect Printer at *172.16.1.21:9100* to LAN as *192.168.1.1:9100* for LAN users. How to write `iptables` rules ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to do port forwarding from the WAN interface to the LAN, this [Wiki](https://itsecureadmin.com/wiki/index.php/Setup_a_Home_Router_using_IPTables) answers your question.

As root, execute the following:

```
export LAN=eth0
export WAN=eth1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ${WAN} -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9100 -i ${WAN} -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1:9100
```

Comment: Hard to believe it can be set without mention `172.16.1.21`.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 9100 -i eth1 -j DNAT --to 172.16.1.21:9100
```

Redirect TCP traffic destined to port 9100 on 192.168.1.1 coming on eth1 to port 9100 on 172.16.1.21. This assumes eth1 is 192.168.1.1 and that traffic passes through the box and leaves it on eth0.

Comment: Explanation needed.

Comment: Redirect TCP traffic destined to port 9100 on 192.168.1.1 coming on eth1  to port 9100 on 172.16.1.21. This assumes eth1 is 192.168.1.1 and that traffic passes through the box and leaves it on eth0. But isn't it selfexplanatory?